# Shell script to monitor a folder daily basis, if new file is NOT GENERATED on that folder, Mail alerts will send

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, unix, automation

Shell script to monitor a folder daily basis, if new file is NOT GENERATED on that folder,  Mail alerts will send

```
#!/bin/sh
Value=`find <Dirpath> -type f -daystart -ctime 0 -print | wc -l`
if [ $Value -gt 0 ]; then
        echo "File got generated"
else
        echo "File not generated Sending mail"
        echo "<Messages>" | mail -s "<Subject of mail>" <Mail_ID>
fi
```

Comment: Have you checked incrond (inotify cron daemon) ?

Comment: No, above code is worked for me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
for f in $PATHTOFOLDER/*; do
  if [[ ! -e "$f" ]]; then
    echo '*** empty folder *************************************'          
 fi
```

Comment: Are you going to explain it?

Comment: You should always include some sort of explanation, research, or some other detail in your answers. Visit [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more information